# Proving that the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are infinite and have an infinite complement is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are infinite and have an infinite complement is uncountable.

I know how to prove that the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$  is uncountable, and how to prove that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, but not how to put those facts together to prove this.

Any hints on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  Consider infinite subsets of the even integers.

Comment: Alternatively, using what you already know... Knowing that the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable, show that the set of *co-finite* subsets is also countable.  If $F=\{X~:~X~\text{is finite}\}$ and $C=\{X~:~X~\text{is cofinite}\}$, recognize that your set is $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)\setminus (F\cup C)$.